# What kind of regularity implies the internal ball condition?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the internal ball condition (at any point $x$ of the bounduary there is a ball contained in $\Omega$ which bounduary contains $x$). What regularity for the bounduary of $\Omega$ dies this imply? I'm pretty sure this is well known, any reference is well appreciated.

Comment: It does not imply Lipschitz. For instance, let $\omega$ be the closed region bounded by the graph of $y = 1$, $x = 0$, and $y = x^{1/2}$.  Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R} \setminus \omega$. This has the internal ball condition, but is not Lipschitz.

Comment: Yep, I know, but I was looking for hoelder at least